# Is each Lebesgue integrable function Riemann integrable almost equal?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

There are numerous functions which are Lebesgue but not Riemann integrable, the most famous one probably being

$$ f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
 1, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

However, changing $f$ on a null set (namely $\mathbb(Q) \cap [0,1]$) could result in a Riemann integrable function.

My question is: Is this true for all Lebesgue but not Riemann integrable functions? If not, are there any counter examples constructable?

Comment: $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$ will do (though perhaps isn't very interesting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the characteristic function of a fat cantor set is not almost equal to any Riemann integrable function.

Comment: After wikipedia–ing “fat cantor set” this sounds plausible, thanks. :)